# Cleanup orphaned wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy

Tags: codex

As a non-tech guy and not familiar with Wordpress Codex, would appreciate any guidance on providing the codex for:

1. cleaning of orphaned wp_terms
2. cleaning of orphaned wp_terms_taxonomy
3. cleaning of wp_options

Comment: Why not ask solutions to these questions and have a proper reference here to what you need. Lets be honest here, this site has much more reliable, more correct and more valuable info than the codex. Anyone with a wordpress.org account can alter the codex as he/she wants, and because of this, some pages in the codex ended up with utter crap and totally incorrect info. IMHO, you'll find better references here in most cases :-)

Comment: Just to add, from experience, it seems most people stop here and look for answers than consulting the codex for answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how WordPress handles the cleanup, check out [`wp_delete_term`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.2/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2440).

Essentially, when a term is deleted WordPress will find all immediate child terms and set their parent to the parent of the deleted term.